# Query string is not coming in fiddler?

Tags: fiddler

In the fiddler i choose the inspectors>webforms to see the query string for the request. But instead it is coming blank. Do i need to enable anything in order to get that? Or any other way. Please help me out.

Comment: This is not the right place to ask - try this site: http://kickmajorbooty.blogspot.co.il/2011/04/query-string-parameters-as-table-for.html or the fiddler2.com web site for additional support

Comment: CAn you share the fiddler?

Comment: This is for the screen shot
http://imageshack.com/a/img440/3126/mqaq.png

Answer (score 0):

The session selected in your screenshot is a JavaScript file that is used by the page in question. Its URL does not contain a query string. Instead, you should select the Session that represents the web page that includes this JS file.